# Keeping a single background thread through a Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading

(Ok, I've made a total mess of this, so I'm going to clean it up and provide all the information I can here.  Please see the bottom of this post for a better explanation of what I'm trying to do.  I'm leaving the rest here in the hopes that someone will see the mess I made and learn how to make a better post from my mistakes. :))

Please see the section entitled "A Better Explanation" for, well, a better explanation.

---

**EDIT 2**: My apologies for being unclear.  `ItemStore` is not a collection in this case, it's a DB-backed service.  I've updated my code.

---

**EDIT**: Additional information.

- The backing store is going to be a DB.  This means that we can persist items in the queue without worrying about losing items if the application dies.  This also means that adding/retrieving items from the DB could be slowish.  (i.e., not as fast as in-memory).
- Because of this, it also means that we don't want to hold a collection in memory the whole time.  The preference is to go back to the DB for the next item, again for persistence safety.
- Ultimately, items are coming in from web service calls.  Essentially, Enqueue will be a WebAPI route that a browser will do an HTTP POST to.
- Finally, the central problem we're trying to solve is to funnel potentially a bunch of requests into a single, FIFO queue, basically due to a limitation in a third-party library we're using.  So the goal is to get, say, 10 simultaneous requests and process them one-by-one.

I don't know how much that additional information helps, but there it is. :)

---

I'm trying to create a simple processing queue.  On `Enqueue`, it adds an item to a store, then checks to see if the processing thread is already running or not.  If it is, it's done; if not, it kicks off the thread that runs the queue.

The queue thread itself queries the store for its next item and process it.  Then it queries the store for its next item, and keeps going until it runs out of items.  Then it stops processing and shuts down until the next item is enqueued.

The code basically looks like this:

```
// Service that saves and retrieves items from a database
private IItemService _service;

// Item processor
private IItemProcessor _itemProcessor;

public void Enqueue(object item)
{
   _service.Save(item);
   if (_isRunning)
   {
      // If the queue is processing, the item just gets added to the DB and
      // the processing function will pull it off of the DB when needed.
      return;
   }

   // If it's not already running, process whatever queue items are in the DB.
   ProcessQueue();
}

private void ProcessQueue()
{
   _workerThread = new ThreadStart(ProcessQueueInternal);
   _workerThread.Start();
}

private void ProcessQueueInternal()
{
   // _service.GetNextItem() retrieves an item from the DB based on several
   // factors, including whether another instance of a queue has claimed it,
   // priority, etc.
   object item;
   while (item = _service.GetNextItem()) != null)
   {
      _itemProcessor.ProcessItem(item);
   }

   // No more items in the DB, so the queue should sit idle until a new
   // item is enqueued.
   _isRunning = false;
}
```

I'm testing out this queue using a `Parallel.ForEach()` loop, like so:

```
Parallel.ForEach(myItems, item => Enqueue(item));
```

The problem I'm running into is that occasionally the queue fires off twice, which I want to avoid.  Not regularly, but it happens enough that I want to prevent that from happening.

How can I get around this?  It's possible that multiple items will be enqueued simultaneously, and I need to make sure that there is only one background thread running at once.  Is the best way something simple, like this?

```
private void ProcessQueue()
{
   if (_workerThread == null || (_workerThread != null && _workerThread.IsAlive))
   {
      _workerThread = new ThreadStart(ProcessQueueInternal);
      _workerThread.Start();
   }
}
```

Or is there a better way?  Simplicity is the goal here, second only to effectiveness.

---

**A Better Explanation**

**Goal**: Funnel a bunch of HTTP requests that can trigger a long running process in such a way so that the process gets run on a single thread.  The workflow is as follows:

1. User sends an HTTP POST (from an Angular site we're also developing) with all the information we need to execute it, including a route to execute.
2. The POST hits a WebAPI `ApiController`, which itself calls a service.

   - The service itself is instantiated through Unity with a `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`, so it's constantly running in the background.  (We've tested that this is the case.)
3. The service adds the data that came in from the POST to a database table via EntityFramework.

   - If the service is already processing items, it simply stops here.
   - If the service is not processing items, it starts to do so.
4. The service processes items by retrieving them, one at a time, from the database.  Each item is processed by getting all of its data and sending off an HTTP POST to another service (which kicks off a process there that can't really be run concurrently, a limitation of a library we're using), then waiting for it to complete.  Once it's complete, it sets the state of that item to Success/Error, then gets the next item from the DB and repeats, until there are no more items in the DB to process.
5. Items are selected from the DB on the basis of priority and whether it's been run before or not (i.e., status is InQueue and not Success/Error).

There are three benefits here that we're aiming for:

1. With the DB as the backing store, we have some safety against the case where the application dies for some reason.
2. The queue doesn't need to keep polling the DB when it runs out of items to process.  It just sits there, idly, until a new item is enqueued, in which case the entire process starts up again.
3. With no backing collection internally, we don't need to worry about data loss when items are pulled out of the DB and the application dies for some reason.  This is related to #1.

The biggest danger we have -- and the problem I'm running into -- is that the ultimate entry point here is a web site, and a button on that site.  So it's entirely possible that 100 people hit the button all at once, and ultimately the process that is at the end of this mess has to run in a serial manner.  So we need to funnel all of those requests down to a single-file line.  As a result, the entire queue should be processed by one thread.  Here I'm using a single thread named `_workerThread`.  The issue I'm having is ensuring that `_workerThread` is instantiated and started once for any cycle.  That is:

- Queue is being processed and a new item comes in: *do not start a new thread*.
- Queue is not being processed and a new item comes in: *start a new thread*.

The only way I could think of to simulate multiple users here is via `Parallel.ForEach`.  I'll explain my testing methodology below.

**Code:** The updated code for the queue service is above.  Specifically, the `Enqueue`, `ProcessQueue`, and `ProcessQueueInternal` are the relevant portions that are causing my problems.  I have updated them to be as clear as possible.  Ultimately, they contain two major parts:

- `_service` is a separate item service, responsible for the simple save, delete, and update methods, as well as pulling the next item off of the queue.  It is inserted into the queue via dependency injection.
- `_itemProcessor` is a separate class responsible for processing the item.  In the real world, it would create an `HttpClient` and fire off the request in the item data.  I split it out mostly so I could create a fake one for unit testing the queue without a database.

**Testing**: I'm trying to test this via unit tests, since we don't yet have the UI hooks necessary to test this in the real world.  To do this, I've made "fake" versions of the item service and the item processor:

- The fake item service just stores new queue items in a `List<WebRequestQueueItem>`.  This could be the cause of my problems right here, now that I think about it, but I'm not sure.  I'm a little afraid that using some sort of thread-safe collection for the fake service would be adding a "fix" for a real-world problem (since when the queue actually goes into use outside of unit tests, it will be using the DB as its backing store).
- The fake item processor just does a `Thread.Sleep` for 1500ms.  It's there to simulate that the ultimate action that's being taken will take a while.

To simulate multiple people hitting the server all at once, I'm using `Parallel.ForEach()`.  I don't know of a better way to simulate this.

**The Problem**: Ultimately the problem is that the `Parallel.ForEach()` loop adds items all at once to the item service, but it's doing so quickly enough that the queue doesn't have time to realize that the items are already being processed.  So it starts off another `_workerThread`, which is exactly what I don't want it to do.

My suspicion is that it's the general process that's broken, not the fact that I'm using `List` as the backing store in this case.  Somehow, I need to make sure that if the item is added very quickly, or if dozens of people add items to the queue all at once, multiple instances of the queue don't get kicked off.  I have found that once the queue kicks off, everything works fine -- new items can be added to it and they'll just get processed when the service gets to it.  But it's that initial start that's causing me problems.

A note about the DB service itself: it's using EntityFramework, and the standard methods for adding/update/deleting items.  The patterns are identical across our entire product, and we've had no problems that I'm aware of yet.  Still, the methods look like this:

*Add*

```
_context.WebRequestQueueItems.Add(someItemEntity);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

*Update*

```
_context.WebRequestQueueItems.AddOrUpdate(someItemEntity);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

*Remove*

```
_context.WebRequestQueueItems.Remove(someItemEntity);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

*GetNextItem (roughly; the clauses are slightly more complicated than this, but you get the idea)*

```
return _context
       .WebRequestQueueItems
       .OrderByDescending(item => item.Priority)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Your code is not thread safe. Stop inventing the wheel and use a built-in class like `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection` or similars.

Comment: @L.B I added some more information to the top of the post, but I'm deliberately trying to avoid using internal collections to manage the queue.  The goal is to funnel a bunch of requests into a single-file line, using the DB to hold the requests for persistence purposes.  I'll look into `BlockingCollection`, though.

Comment: `deliberately trying to avoid using internal collections to manage the queue` What you are trying to do is exactly this. So I still insist on BlockingCollection. But There are alse other profesional solutions like MSMQ RabbitMQ IBM's MQ etc. (Infact , it is simple producer-consumer problem if you know what you are doing)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how I'm doing exactly that.  I may have made it unclear in the code snippets, but if we assume that `ItemStore` is a service that gets or saves a single item from the DB at a time (which it actually is in my code), does it change anything?  (If that's the case, I can update the code snippets.)

Comment: "deliberately trying to avoid using internal collections to manage the queue" - `ItemStore` is an internal collection which is managing your queue. From your description it sounds like `ItemStore` is not thread-safe.

Comment: I understand that you're using `Parallel.ForEach(myItems, item => Enqueue(item));` to test your code, but what is calling `Enqueue` in your real code? Is it a collection? And event? What's the source of the items you're enqueuing?

Comment: @Enigmativity I see what you're saying, and I was unclear.  I'll update my code now.  `ItemStore` is actually a service -- it adds an item to the DB, then gets the appropriate next item to process (priority is a consideration here, so the first item in is not necessarily the next item out).  As for  the source of the items, it's a service that runs behind a WebAPI route.  So multiple web requests can come in at once, which is what I was trying to simulate with `Parallel.ForEach()`.

Comment: @AriRoth - So I would like to see the life-cycle of your data from the point at which you get it (i.e. how does the web request come in? Is it an event firing, etc?) - and what processing happens on that request to generate items and how I know when I'm don't processing, etc. What you're doing probably has a very simple solution but you've only drip-fed us bits of your process and it's hard to properly advise. We need to know the full process and the underlying business requirement.

Comment: @Enigmativity I understand.  This was probably not my best post ever. :)  I'm not sure how to get you the information you're asking for without making a total mess of my post with edits or spamming comments.  I guess I'll add another edit, clean the post up, and let you know when I've done so. :)

Comment: @AriRoth - It's best to just add to the end of your existing question - that's helps make it easy for future readers to understand the evolution of the question and how the comments relate. So try **not** to clean up your question too much.

Comment: @AriRoth - You know that your DB-backed service is probably not thread-safe. We need to see the full process flow when you can.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ok, I've added as much of an explanation as I could think of.    I'm a little worried at this point that I'm running out of space to add to the post. :)

Comment: @AriRoth - I appreciate the effort you've gone through to describe the issue. But, what I'm understanding here is that you're polling the database periodically to see if there are any items and then you are draining the database using a separate thread. Then repeating this process. Is that right?

Comment: @Enigmativity Close.  I'm polling the DB for the next item (one at a time, not a batch) for as long as the DB will give me one, but once the DB returns no new item I quit polling.  Then I don't restart the process until a new item item is queued up.    (It might have short bursts of activity followed by long periods of nothing, so I don't want to poll when I know I have no items to process.)  Also, asking the DB for a new item happens on the process thread, not a separate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, try this code:

```
private static object _gate = new object();

private void ProcessQueue()
{
    if (_workerThread == null || (_workerThread != null && _workerThread.IsAlive))
    {
        lock (_gate)
        {
            if (_workerThread == null || (_workerThread != null && _workerThread.IsAlive))
            {
                _workerThread = new ThreadStart(ProcessQueueInternal);
                _workerThread.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code will prevent two threads from starting at the same time, but it does not prevent the situation where a thread goes idle after the first `if` but before the second. You have to ensure that you call `ProcessQueue` in more than one place to ensure your queue doesn't stop.